# Why does std::getline overwrite char array containing filename?

Tags: c++, linux

When I run the following code, `foobar_fname` gets overwritten by the contents of `foobar_fname` when `getline` runs:

```
ostringstream st_foobar_fname;
st_foobar_fname << foostr << BAR_CONST << barstr;
const char *foobar_fname = (st_foobar_fname.str()).c_str();

ifstream foobar_file(foobar_fname);
debug("Reading '%s'", foobar_fname);

string foobar_def = "";
if (getline(foobar_file, foobar_def)) {
  debug("'%s' reported message '%s'", foobar_fname, foobar_def.c_str());
} else {
  error("Unable to read '%s'", foobar_fname);
}
```

For example, if `foobar_fname=/home/user/fname` and `/home/user/fname` contains 'simple-text-content', the output looks like:

```
Reading '/home/user/fname'
'simple-text-content' reported message 'simple-text-content'
```

However, if `/home/user/fname` doesn't exist (and `getline` fails), the output is correct:

```
Reading '/home/user/fname'
Unable to read '/home/user/fname'
```

Where am I going wrong?

(This is a piece of old code that I don't want to introduce new dependencies for, so c++11, boost, etc are not workable solutions).

Comment: Could you please be so kind and provide use with a [MCVE], here's [something for starters](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d4727423864d880e). (or at least try ideone, providing standard input is easier there)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing the symptoms of undefined behavior.

```
st_foobar_fname.str()
```

returns a `std::string`.

```
const char *foobar_fname = (st_foobar_fname.str()).c_str();
```

stores a pointer that is not valid after the line finishes executing since it corresponds to a temporary object. The temporary object gets destroyed and you are left with a dangling pointer.

If you want to keep the value around, use a `std::string`.

```
std::string foobar_fname = st_foobar_fname.str();
```